# How can I change line endings in my text file automatically?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, linefeed

I have a .TXT files with both CRLF and LF as line endings.

The file is generated in windows only,still it has both CRLF and LF line endings.( As per my understanding, files in windows have CRLF whereas Unix has LF not both- correct me if am wrong.)

Also I have more such files, how to automate this process of replacing LF with CRLF .

Could anyone help me with it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related (possibly even a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/3994909/10871073

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop Visual Studio from mixing line endings in files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994909/stop-visual-studio-from-mixing-line-endings-in-files)

Comment: @Dominique, Thanks for suggesting the link. I have seen this...the problem is similar. But the I made tools settings as suggested, still no use.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I got a solution to replace these line endings externally for multiple files using notepad++ .                        Still wonder why those files have mixed line endings.